# How would distinct lead to more returned items

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) name,
    CONCAT(em.first_name, ' ', em.last_name) manager
FROM
    Employees E
JOIN Dept_Emp DE ON E.emp_no = DE.emp_no
JOIN Dept_Manager DM ON DM.dept_no = DE.dept_no
JOIN Employees EM ON EM.emp_no = DM.emp_no
ORDER BY
    E.last_name,
    E.first_name
```

I get 886026 items returned.

If I remove the DISTINCT key word I get 300024. How is that possible shouldn't if anything DISTINCT limit my returned items?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` cannot return more rows than before the `DISTINCT`.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour when you work on IDs only ?     
    `SELECT DISTINCT E.emp_no, DM.emp_no
   FROM
       Employees E
   JOIN Dept_Emp DE ON E.emp_no = DE.emp_no
   JOIN Dept_Manager DM ON DM.dept_no = DE.dept_no`

Comment: Interesting. when I work only with the IDs I get the same  886026, Why is that?